# How to get Advanced Rest Client to work with socket.io

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to use Advanced Rest Client (a Chrome extension/app) with socket.io, but it does not connect to my NodeJS socket.io server.

Is the problem perhaps that I cannot use ws://localhost and have to use another protocol first? I know that socket.io does support the WebSocket protocol, though.

Or perhaps there is another extension or app specifically for socket.io..?

Any help is greatly appreciated.